# Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzea

Tags: java, android, firebase

I need help. I got this error message (Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzea) when I added: **implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.0'**  in my app gradle build file.
Everything was Okay untill I added this one line of code in my gradle file.

This is my build gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fortnite.playerstats"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.0'
}
```

another gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while
>   merging dex archives:
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\97.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\108.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\119.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\152.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\130.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\141.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\56.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\54.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\55.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\51.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\53.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\52.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar
>   Learn how to resolve the issue at
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
>   Program type already present:
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzea  at
>   com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor491.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while
>   merging dex archives:
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\97.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\108.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\119.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\152.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\130.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\141.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\56.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\54.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar,
>   C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\FortnitePlayerStats\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar,

Answer (score 4):

I have fixed the issue by changing:
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'

to

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.**4**'

Comment: I didn't have firebase but I dropped com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics from 16.0.5 back to 16.0.4 after seeing your suggestion, as I got the same error as you after upgrading from com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads 17.0.0 to 17.1.0